# Full-text index on a view or a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, fulltext-index

We are going to do a full-text index on a view. But while trying to create a clustered index on a view it is showing an error like "`Cannot create index. Object was created with the following SET options off: 'ANSI_NULLS'.`"

So with reference to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010042/update-ansi-nulls-option-in-an-existing-table)

the only option to avoid this is to drop and recreate the table.

So before doing this i am asking whether i can do a full text index for the table itself than creating an index on the view. ie select the result from table for the search and then select the corresponding data from the view.

Is there any performance related issues while doing a full text index on a table compared with full-text index on a view.? Please give your suggestions?

Comment: the question is: Why is ANSI_NULLS set to off?  Fix the real problem...

Comment: @MitchWheat : actually we dont know.. why the previous vendors do like that.. now we have to do the full-text index on this view or table..

Comment: @MitchWheat: whether this option will cause any other problem really?